# Changes after last 6.10.0-r19i.8185 BixbyStudio

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I have issues after last update of BixbyStudio to version 6.10.0-r19i.8185 after submission as public or private:

1. When using simuator (or device) Im getting an error message: **Missing a mock for Installed Apps. Add "appId": "com.samsung.android.bixby.service" and "appVersion": "1" to the apps.json file. For more info: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/ide.simulator#mock-installed-apps**. When I go to this url there is no any inforation about this apps.json. Do you have information where I can put this file and can read more about it?
2. I have capsule with audio:

```
capsule {
  id (my.app)
  version (0.4.0)
  format (3)
  targets {
    target (bixby-mobile-en-US)
  }
  capsule-imports {
      import (bixby.audioPlayer) {
        version (0.3.1)
        as (audioPlayer)
      }
  }
}
```

which generates from that BixbyStudio for me deprecation warning
**import '0.3.1-bixby.audioPlayer' does not declare itself as 'library' and will not be importable in the future**, but im using same version from that document https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/sample-capsules/samples/audio
Please explain what is wrong here

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Support for testing audio library in Simulator is not available yet. However, you should be able to test the same on an actual device.

The next iteration of Simulator is expected to support audio.bixbyPlayer in a couple of weeks from now.

Re: **import '0.3.1-bixby.audioPlayer' does not declare itself as 'library' and will not be importable in the future,** you can ignore this warning for now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using audio player with simulator is a feature not yet available, but on-device testing should work. This new feature will be included in future release. However, I cannot confirm a definitive date.

   - No mocking in IDE is supported at the moment, this is a feature not yet available. There is **NO way** to invoke audio player or any other installed apps in simulator.
   - To confirm the audio player feature is working correctly on device. Please download [example.meow](https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-samples-collection) and do private submission (you may need to change namespace) on your device. This is a large repository, the example.meow capsule is in subfolder audio. After confirming example.meow is working correctly, you can follow the syntax as an example in your capsule.
2. Good news! With the new 19I release and version (0.3.2), we finally got rid of the warning. And so is many other library capsules, please update your IDE and use the new version published [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library).

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answers. So

1. Yes, I know that audio is not in support from simulator yet, thats fine!
But question was there that we need some apps.json - Missing a mock for Installed Apps. Add "appId": "com.samsung.android.bixby.service" and "appVersion": "1" to the apps.json file. For more info: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/ide.simulator#mock-installed-apps
Seems this is not decribed anywhere.
And ion real device its is not working also
Please help!
2. Yes, version 0.3.2 works (means I dont have that error/warning in BixbyStudio)
Please advise!

Answer (score -1):

I'm also seeing this error also and can't find any information about where this file should be placed.

Missing a mock for Installed Apps. Add "appId": "com.samsung.android.bixby.service" and "appVersion": "1" to the apps.json file.

Comment: Right now, the Simulator does not support a way to test the audio library. The error message you are seeing is part of the features that are being built right now to allow the Simulator to test the bixby.audioPlayer capsule library.

This information will be mentioned in the Release Notes when it happens but we will also update this thread.

Comment: Thanks, I will wait. But I thinked on real device it will work at least...

I tryed audio 0.3.3 (from meow example) + runtime flags from https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-samples-collection/blob/master/audio/capsule.bxb

still this Missing a mock for Installed Apps. Add "appId": "com.samsung.android.bixby.service" and "appVersion": "1" to the apps.json file. For more info: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/ide.simulator#mock-installed-apps

rechecked, no any mock files....
so waiting, thanks!